# Why did Donald Trump say "I walk in the street"? Shouldn't it be "I walk on the street"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Donald Trump said "***I walk in the street***" at **0.51** [Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-DSfvYCKwY)

Shouldn't it be "***I walk on the street***"? Is this an error?

Comment: "and I watch them up there **walking** the streets"

Comment: @CopperKettle, if that is the case, then he got a pronunciation mistake his "*ing*" sounds like "*in*". Very confusing

Comment: @CopperKettle, why not "*walking on the street*". He missed the preposition "*on*"?

Comment: I'm not a pronunciation specialist, but I guess people often do not articulate the word-final **g** in -ing endings.

Comment: There is no need for the preposition **on** in the line of text I quoted.

Comment: @CopperKettle, "*I walk the streets*" does not make any sense!

Comment: He does not say "I walk the streets", he sayd "**them**". He watches other politicians walking the streets, and sees no use in it.

Comment: @CopperKettle, so "***watch somebody/something doing something***": *to look at somebody/something for a time, paying attention to what happens* (http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/watch_1?q=watch)? Got it

Comment: @CopperKettle, I think it should be "***watch them up there walking on the street***", why there is no "**on**" in his sentence

Comment: You can "walk the street" with no preposition.

Comment: @Tom: Trump's -ing does not sound like "in".  The quality of the vowel in his suffix changes significantly in anticipation of the -ng, and the [ŋg] is quite audible. The phrase "walking the streets" is a perfectly idiomatic variant, as CopperKettle says.  Here it refers to the other candidates being out among the crowds, soliciting votes.

Comment: He actually says: "I watch them up there walking the streets."

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

> ...walk **on** the street..

Would be interpreted by a native speaker as literally **on top** of the  the ***surface*** of the street.

The **in** in Trump's quote is a **colloquialism** particularly used with **walking** :

> ...walk **in** the street...

referring to the street and its environment. What Trump is saying is that he has **seen** and **experienced** what the average person **sees** and **experiences**. That he is in touch with the public since given his status and wealth, one might not expect him to do this. He might have said:

> I **walk** the streets

but this would have a slightly different meaning.

This should not be confused with:

> They found her doll **in** the street.

which means the doll was found within **the boundaries** of the street.